# Gostaria se alguém consegue identificar meu erro nesse código em python:

Tags: python

```
def main ():

    d=[(1, 'Introdução a Sistemas de Informação'), (1, 'Programação I'), (1, 'Introdução ao Computador'), (1, 'Introdução ao Cálculo'), (1, 'Lógica'), (1, 'Comunicação e Expressão'), (2, 'Programação II'), (2, 'Teoria Geral da Administração'), (2, 'Cálculo I'), (2, 'Matemática Discreta'), (2, 'Sociologia'), (3, 'Teoria Geral de Sistemas'), (3, 'Estruturas de Dados'), (3, 'Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores'), (3, 'Álgebra Linear'), (3, 'Probabilidade e Estatística I'), (3, 'Metodologia de Pesquisa'), (0, 'Cálculo II'), (0, 'Desenvolvimento Orientado a Objeto')]
    for i in d: 
        if i[0]!=0:
            print (i[0], "Período:")
            x=i[0]
            for j in d:
                if j[0]==x:
                    print ("- ", j[1])
        else:
            print("Optativas:")
            if i[0]==0:
                print("- ", i[1])
                y=i[1]
                for j in d:
                    if j[0]==0:
                        w=j[1]
                        if w!=y:
                            print ("- ", j[1])

main ()
```

Na execução aparece assim:

```
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
2 Período:
-  Programação II
-  Teoria Geral da Administração
-  Cálculo I
-  Matemática Discreta
-  Sociologia
2 Período:
-  Programação II
-  Teoria Geral da Administração
-  Cálculo I
-  Matemática Discreta
-  Sociologia
2 Período:
-  Programação II
-  Teoria Geral da Administração
-  Cálculo I
-  Matemática Discreta
-  Sociologia
2 Período:
-  Programação II
-  Teoria Geral da Administração
-  Cálculo I
-  Matemática Discreta
-  Sociologia
2 Período:
-  Programação II
-  Teoria Geral da Administração
-  Cálculo I
-  Matemática Discreta
-  Sociologia
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
Optativas:
-  Cálculo II
-  Desenvolvimento Orientado a Objeto
Optativas:
-  Desenvolvimento Orientado a Objeto
-  Cálculo II

Mas deveria ser assim:
1 Período:
-  Introdução a Sistemas de Informação
-  Programação I
-  Introdução ao Computador
-  Introdução ao Cálculo
-  Lógica
-  Comunicação e Expressão
2 Período:
-  Programação II
-  Teoria Geral da Administração
-  Cálculo I
-  Matemática Discreta
-  Sociologia
3 Período:
-  Teoria Geral de Sistemas
-  Estruturas de Dados
-  Arquitetura e Organização de Computadores
-  Álgebra Linear
-  Probabilidade e Estatística I
-  Metodologia de Pesquisa
Optativas:
-  Desenvolvimento Orientado a Objeto
-  Cálculo II
```

Comment: O primeiro loop está passando por todos as tuplas do array, depois logo em seguida você faz um segundo loop com todos os itens do array novamente... É isso que está causando o erro. Ou você faz uma delas estática, ou então usa lambda para agrupar elas, até porque isso deixaria o código bem mais bonito.

Comment: Sim, pois foi o unico jeito que achei para imprimir como eu quero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom seu código poderia ser melhorado de diversas maneiras, porém vamos focar apenas em como deixar ele correto. O problema é devido a várias repetições que seu código possui(`for j in d:`), você percorre a lista e percorre ela novamente em dois `for`'s encadeados.

Por exemplo depois de pegar o primeiro item e retornar o período e seus itens você passa pro próximo item e também pega o período e reimprime tudo novamente.

```
->(1, 'Introdução a Sistemas de Informação'), 
  # você pega este item imprime o período inteiro na próxima interação 
  # você pega o item de baixo imprime o período e imprime ele inteiro 
  # novamente, você reimprime o período o mesmo numero de itens que ele
  # possui
  (1, 'Programação I'), 
  (1, 'Introdução ao Computador'), 
  (1, 'Introdução ao Cálculo'), 
  (1, 'Lógica'), 
  (1, 'Comunicação e Expressão')
```

Para que você não imprima as opções além da necessária basta aplicar uma variável  aux.

```
    aux = None
    for i in d: 
        if i[0] != aux:
            aux = i[0]            

            if i[0]!=0:
                print (i[0], "Período:")
                x=i[0]
                for j in d:
                    if j[0]==x:
                        print ("- ", j[1])
            else:
                print("Optativas:")
                if i[0]==0:
                    print("- ", i[1])
                    y=i[1]
                    for j in d:
                        if j[0]==0:
                            w=j[1]
                            if w!=y:
                                print ("- ", j[1])
```

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada!!!!